# Sequence of images flickering on scroll in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, sequence

I am creating a simple animation that would show a sequence of many images (about 200) on page scroll in jQuery. The following code works fine in Chrome and Safari, but the images flicker in Firefox. I tried every possible solution including preolading the images and reducing file sizes, nothing works.

```
    var nextImage = "frames/1.png";
    var i=0;
    var myAnim = function(){
        $(".myImageHolder").attr('src', nextImage);
        i++;
        nextImage="frames/"+i+".png";
        //console.log(nextImage);
    };

    $(window).on("scroll",function() {
        myAnim();
    });
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Have You tried using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` ?

Comment: It doesn't help. It is still the same. I am even trying to show() and hide() images. The problem still exists. I am loading all images, then hiding them. I am displaying current image on scroll event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution was to compress the images, and to convert PNG-24 to PNG-8.
Reducing the number and size of images can solve this issue.